# Python: Appending system path to import the module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a module from the prgoram called 'Power factory" in Python. The folder where power factory file located looks as follow:

[image]

I have written a script to import the powerfactory module as follow:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("PAth of folder")
import powerfactory as pf
```

When I ran the above code, it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing powerfactory: The specified module could not be found.
```

I copied the .dll file present in the power factory folder into the Python DLL folder but no luck. Could anyone help me where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: @AMC yes, that's the entire error message

Comment: How did you specify the folder path?

Answer (score 1):

Searching the net I found this (from [here](https://www.digsilent.de/en/faq-reader-powerfactory/python-dll-load-failed.html))

> I am not able to import powerfactory module: DLL load failed Category:
> Scripting
>
> If an error message appears when importing the powerfactory module
> stating “ DLL load failed: the specified module could not be found”,
> this means that Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio
> 2012 package is not installed on the computer.
>
> To overcome this problem the user should add the PowerFactory
> installation directory to the os path variable within his python
> script.
>
> ```
> import os
>
> os.environ["PATH"] = r'C:\Program Files\DIgSILENT\PowerFactory 2016;' + os.environ["PATH"]
> ```

Comment: @Dharman I already tried that but it did not work

Comment: @user2293224 This is not my answer. I only edited it. Please do not ping me.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the .dll file from your digsilent folder, eg. `Program Files\DIgSILENT\PowerFactory 2020 SP2A\Python\3.8\boost_python38-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.dll`

and place the .dll file directly in your system!

Save it to your `C:\Windows\System32` folder.
&
Save it also to your `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder.

You should be good to go.